# allow duplicates in JSON array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I have this code that creates a JSON array for all the text within the html class `name`. But if there are two of the same for example:

```
<a class="name">Hey</a>
<a class="name">Hey</a>
```

the JSON array would look like this

```
{"names":["Hey"]}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
{"names":["Hey","Hey"]}
```

---

### PHP:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxx.co.uk/xxxxx.html');


function linkExtractor($html)
{
    $doc  = new DOMDocument();
    $last = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($last);
    $xp     = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' name ')]") as $node)
        $result[trim($node->textContent)] = 1;
    return array_keys($result);
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "names" => linkExtractor($html)
));
?>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder like so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working way too hard there. :-)

```
function linkExtractor($html){ 
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $last = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 
    $doc->loadHTML($html); 
    libxml_use_internal_errors($last); 
    $xp = new DOMXPath($doc); 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' name ')]") as $node) 
        $result[] = trim($node->textContent); // Just push the result here, don't assign it to a key (as that's why you're overwriting)

    // Now return the array, rather than extracting keys from it
    return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use them as array-keys:

```
$result[trim($node->textContent)] = 1;
```

And a key is unique within an array. Just use

```
$result[] = trim($node->textContent);
```

(and of course `return $result;` instead of `return array_keys($result);`)